# Background Colour in UIView not showing

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, view

I have a UIView that should show two colours, red and orange, based on the value of `rating: Double` The problem is that when I run the app nothing is showing up. In my output log the function prints that it has run and that the rating value is what it should be. So I am not sure why nothing is showing up when I run the app, I just see white.

```
class RatingViewController: UIView {

var rating: Double = 1.0
var rate: Double? {
    didSet {
        rating = rate!
        setUpView()
    }
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)


}

private func setUpView() {
  Self.backgroundcolor = UIColor.yellow  
    print("rating is \(rating), and width is \((UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(rating/10)))")
    let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(rating/10))
    var view: UIView
    view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(view)


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add setUpView in `init(:` method

```
class RatingViewController: UIView {

    var rating: Double = 1.0

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    init(frame: CGRect, rate: Double) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.rating = rate
        setUpView()
    }
    private func setUpView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        print("rating is \(rating), and width is \((UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(rating/10)))")
        let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(rating/10))
        var view: UIView
        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.size.height))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Now you can call this class with custom init method like that:

```
// chnage frame and rate according to your requirment  
let rView = RatingViewController(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 300), rate: 2.0)
```

Comment: It still doesn’t work, also if I do that then it runs setUpView() before the rating variable gets updated.

Comment: I am fairly new to swift, could you please show me how to do so, I was trying previously but got a variety or errors.